# toggle $inc field in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, toggle

Is there a way I can toggle the count of a field in MongoDB/mongoose in a single operation? Right now my field is getting incremented with each click `{ $inc: { attending: 1 } }` like so. I want to say if the field `attending` is already at 1 then change it back to 0, and if it is 0 then continue to increment by 1 again. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following...

```
Collection.aggregate(
    [{
        attending: {
        $inc: {
              $cond: { 
                if: { $eq: [ "attending", 1 ] }, 
                then: 1,
                else: -1,
              }
            }
        }
      }]);
```

Please, replace `Collection` with the name of your collection